# Retroactively set text files to binary with git

Tags: git, version-control, git-rewrite-history

We have some files that go back a long ways that haven't been touched in a long while, and we realized the other day that they weren't marked as binary files.

Is there any way to rewrite our history to retroactively to apply the `binary` status to these files?

Comment: I am not the most knowledgable on the subject but I think this can be controlled with attributes and, if that is the case, you can change attributes in .git/info/attributes and then there is no need to rewrite anything (unless you _really_ want to rewrite retroactively so that everybody shares the same stuff). Check https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

Comment: Does it matter for existing commits? Adapting the `.gitattributes` file should be enough going forward, as binary/text only affects merging anyway

Comment: It does matter for existing commits in our case. We're trying to clean up the commit history itself. Changing `.gitattributes` works fine for now and for the future since we caught this issue, but we'd like to fix it if possible.

Comment: Then feel free to change it by rewriting history.... but well, you know that rewriting has implications well beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @Slbox: does that mean the new question is "how to add a file to the root commit"?

Comment: The files are already in previous commits. I'm not sure I know the answer to your question @knittl. Regarding the implications of rewriting history, yes I'm aware I'm asking for someone to give me fire to play with here.

Comment: @Slbox it seems like you are asking how to modify `.gitattributes` in an old commit or add it to the initial commit (=root commit) of the repository. Is that the case or do you need to know something else?